# What to do when the OP refuses to provide clarification?

Tags: discussion

I think the title says it all, however I am referring in particular to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/796836/271). The situation goes like this:

- I see an question that I might be able to answer however it lacks some details I need to know
- I leave a comment asking for clarification
- The OP basically says: *hey, answer my question!*
- I explain that first I need the aforementioned information
- The OP gets mad ranting something about the number of my answers and how I don't want to answer the question

Apart from flagging the last comment as not constructive (already done), what is the best way to handle this situation?

Comment: He did respond... http://askubuntu.com/questions/796836/problems-with-disk-layout-configurations-mate-16-04-64bit#comment1224673_796836

Comment: @AndroidDev that comment has been edited by a mod after I flagged it, my question talks about the big amount of rants that was present **before.**

Comment: Oh. I had no way of knowing it was edited :)

Comment: Could you include a screenshot of what it was before?

Comment: @AndroidDev, the first part of the comment was «Is it so crazy to ask that consideration ? AndreaLazzarotto Well don't bother, is that an 11» and then it went on something like "answers/per year I see there? Your account could be bogus" or something like this that I don't recall exactly.

Comment: @AndroidDev technically you could've seen because edited comments have a little pencil after them. :P Although I also only noticed recently about this feature. And yes, it was a big mistake on my part not to take a screenshot when I could.

Comment: Yes, I nicely asked for her to consider that option and then she went , Huh?

Comment: Was my suggestion such idiocy ?

Comment: @userDepth Do you have a screenshot of the original comments before they got cleaned up, just out of curiosity to understand what has happened?

Comment: @userDepth - I courteously ask why you didn't provide her with the requested information before asking her to answer.

Comment: Is it so crazy to ask that consideration ? AndreaLazzarotto Well don't bother, is that an 11 ratio answers per year I see there? Your account could be bogus - I don't believe he didn't have the actual text copied from the platform because that ( OP comment ) is the nearly exact text. I removed the comment because I re-read the profile and it is not clear that my reasoning about the boguness to be true. He missed "ratio"  but he knows to use formatting for the word "before"

Comment: @AndroidDev Because I was visiting someone and wasn't at my computer

Comment: @userDepth - Ah. As I do not want to start more conflict, I'll just say that next time, please provide the requested info before asking for an answer. Let's keep the peace here. No harm's been done; nobody downvoted your question. (As a matter of fact, it has 2 upvotes). Let's learn from this experience and move on :)

Comment: Begging for an answer that cannot be given is quite impolite (as if I magically knew the answer without any clarification and I wanted to keep it for me), this is kind of obvious. By the way, you guys could at least stop referring to me as if I were a female, that would be very much appreciated. :)

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto - Sorry :) Between your picture and userDepth using "she", I made a bad assumption.

Comment: If soneone handles his or her question in a bad way, obstructs posting a good answer in any way, that's a reason for me to downvote it.

Comment: This user is omitting that I asked a favor to consider a form of answer to the question. And is effectively getting down-votes on my direct approach to the post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If a question author does not cooperate and refuses to provide the necessary information you need to find an appropriate answer, just ignore their question and move on. They had their chance to get your help, but if they don't manage respond properly, it is not your fault. Maybe it would be appropriate to flag or vote to close the question as unclear.

As the user is even (more or less harshly) insulting you, flag the question or comment as offensive and move on. The moderators will deal with it. I see no reason why you should keep trying to help somebody who obviously does not want your help.

Comment: And consider invite to chat

Comment: @userDepth I can't tell how the comment thread between you two has looked initially, I only see its current state. Therefore my answer is rather general than specific to your case. However, in general, if somebody insults me in comments (whether you have done that or not), I won't have the lightest motivation to go on arguing with this person in another location. That's why I personally would not invite the other one to chat in such a situation (and people <50 points may not chat by default at all).

Comment: @ByteCommander check out the comments on the Q for a rough idea of the content of the moderated comment.

Answer (score -6):

I haven't refused. I wasn't at my computer at the moment. A suggestion, don't use idioms if you are not a native speaker. Being idioms and Huh's not formal forms of expressions you will be misunderstood and those are not a the local dictionary shop.

Comment: Did you prefer a "what?" Seriously, how do you want people to answer your questions after they asked for clarification? Do you believe people leave comments just for fun because they don't want to tell you the answer?

Comment: What are you trying to say here?

Comment: @guntbert the use of "Huh?" It really got me by surprise I recognize that. I didn't command to answer in any way. I said "please consider" That expression really seemed apathetic and implied I asked for something stupid or inconceivable. And then I find this here at Meta posted while I was heading home. Maybe he tried to imply he didn't understand my request but in that case I think the way to go is asking Why, for me it is obvious that I was proposing an answer alternative.